# How to profile memory usage and performances of an openMPI program in C

Tags: profiling, memory-management, mpi

I'm looking for a way to profile my openMPI program in C, i'm using openMPI 1.3 with Linux Ubuntu 9.10 and my programs are run under a Intel Duo T1600.

what I want in profile is cache-misses, memory usage and execution time in any part of the program.

thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at gprof and at Intel's VTune. Valgrind with the cachegrind tool could be useful, too.

Comment: Regarding gprof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Answer (score 2):

For Linux I recommend [Zoom](http://rotateright.com) for this kind of profiling. You can get a free 30 day evaluation in order to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found graphical tools for mpi profilling

vampir : www.vampir.eu and 
paraprof at http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs/paraprof/index.html

enjoy

Answer (score 1):

[Allinea MAP](http://www.allinea.com/products/map) is ideal for this. It will highlight poor cache performance, memory usage and execution time right down to the source lines in your code. There is no need to recompile or instrument the application in order to profile it with Allinea MAP - which makes it unusually easy to get started with. On most HPC systems and with most MPIs it takes your binary, runs it, and loads up the source code automatically to display the recorded performance data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [profiling MPI](http://nf.nci.org.au/wiki/Profiling/MPI). Some tools for profiling is [mpiP](http://mpip.sourceforge.net/) and [pgprof](http://www.pgroup.com/products/pgprof.htm).

Comment: profilling MPI link is broken, do you have a redirect?